SVG Contoured Stroke Gradients?
I was doing some SVG banners for my website, and I was wondering:  Is it possible to use gradients to make the stroke mimic the pixel art in the following image?

I used pixel art here to make an outline of each letter going from red through orange, to yellow, and I was wondering if SVG has this capability, or some other way to mimic the results.

I think this is more a filter kind of thing, probably feMorphology with dilate.

Here's how you would do a feMorphology based filter to get that effect


body {
  background-color: black;
}
<svg width="800px" height="600px">
  <defs>
<filter id="colorize" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="1"/>
  <feColorMatrix result="yellow" type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 
                                       0 1 0 0 0
                                       0 0 0 0 0 
                                       0 0 0 1 0"/>
    <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="1"/>
  <feColorMatrix result="orange" type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 
                                       0 0.6 0 0 0
                                       0 0 0 0 0 
                                       0 0 0 1 0"/>
  <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="1"/>
  <feColorMatrix result="red" type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 
                                       0 0 0 0 0
                                       0 0 0 0 0 
                                       0 0 0 1 0"/>
  <feFlood flood-color="black"/>
  <feComposite result="black" operator="in" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
  
    <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in= "red"/>
        <feMergeNode in= "orange"/>    
        <feMergeNode in= "yellow"/>
    <feMergeNode in="black"/>
   </feMerge>
  </filter>
    
  </defs>

<g filter="url(#colorize)">
  <text x="50" y="50" style="font-size:60px" fill="white">Sample Text</text>
  </g>
</svg>



If you want to make your base text more pixelated, you can remove text anti-aliasing using a feComponentTransfer on the alpha channel. Add more 0's to the start of the feFuncA tableValues array for a crispier effect - it will convert more of the anti-aliased edge to fully transparent.


body {
  background-color: black;
}
<svg width="800px" height="600px">
  <defs>
<filter id="colorize" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <feComponentTransfer result="crispyText">
    <feFuncA type="discrete" tableValues="0 0 0 1"/>
  </feComponentTransfer>
  
  <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="1"/>
  <feColorMatrix result="yellow" type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 
                                       0 1 0 0 0
                                       0 0 0 0 0 
                                       0 0 0 1 0"/>
    <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="1"/>
  <feColorMatrix result="orange" type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 
                                       0 0.6 0 0 0
                                       0 0 0 0 0 
                                       0 0 0 1 0"/>
  <feMorphology operator="dilate" radius="1"/>
  <feColorMatrix result="red" type="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0 
                                       0 0 0 0 0
                                       0 0 0 0 0 
                                       0 0 0 1 0"/>
  <feFlood flood-color="black"/>
  <feComposite result="black" operator="in" in2="crispyText"/>
  
    <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in= "red"/>
        <feMergeNode in= "orange"/>    
        <feMergeNode in= "yellow"/>
    <feMergeNode in="black"/>
   </feMerge>
  </filter>
    
  </defs>

<g filter="url(#colorize)">
  <text x="50" y="50" style="font-size:60px" fill="white">Sample Text</text>
  </g>
</svg>



